# Php adding xml for no reason

Tags: php, xml

I am calling a database query and using a foreach loop to display results, however it is causing a W3C error and on inspection I have found that it is adding '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' to my first echo...I have no idea why?? I have moved my php from the very top of the file to the body but still the same problem :(

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post the PHP code since that is where the problem is.

Comment: I've edited my post with more information.

Comment: @magnolia
there is no sense in lines after `return`. they are newer executed.
then move them before `return` or remove...

Answer (score 1):

Where are you seeing the <xml ... > header? Note that if you are viewing this in the browser source, the browser will generally automatically add this if the doctype is XHTML.